# update_cognitive_models.ps1 -RemoteToLocal overwriting remote Luis

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I have updated my dispatch model on the Luis portal then ran `./Deployment/Scripts/update_cognitive_models.ps1 -RemoteToLocal`
but this is overwriting my Luis models on the portal instead of updating my local models, am I missing something?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the issue?What parameters are you passing?

Comment: Strange. It shouldn't do that. You *could* try: `./Deployment/Scripts/update_cognitive_models.ps1 -RemoteToLocal:$true` to ensure that the switch is set properly (it should anyhow).

Can you share the output of the command? You should **not** be seeing anything like 'Replacing faq QnA kb' (I know we're talking LUIS and not QnA, but just an example) which would indicate it is updating the remote models.